# Why does this regular expression match?

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to enlarge my regexp knowledge but I have no clue why the following returns true:

```
/[A-Z]{2}/.test("ABC")
// returns true
```

I explicity put `{2}` in the expression which should mean that only exactly two capital letters match.

According to http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html:

> Omitting both the comma and max tells the engine to repeat the token exactly min times.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must anchor the regex using `^` and `$` to indicate the start and end of the string.

```
/^[A-Z]{2}$/.test("ABC")
// returns false
```

Your current regex matches the "AB" part of the string.

Answer (score 1):

It's matching `AB`, the first two letters of `ABC`.

To do an entire match, use the `^` and `$` anchors:

```
/^[A-Z]{2}$/.test("ABC")
```

This matches an entire string of exactly 2 capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `^[A-Z]{2}$` to match only the whole string rather than parts of it. In your sample, the regex matches `AB` - which are indeed two capital letters in a row.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `^` and `$` characters in your regexp - beginning of the string and end of the string. Because they are missing your regular expression says "2 characters", but not "only two characters", so its matching either "AB" or "BC" in your string...

Answer (score 1):

The doc don't lie :)

> Omitting both the comma and max tells the engine to repeat the token exactly min times.

It says **min times** not max times

Comment: Exactly min times, which means exactly 2 if I use `{2}` as min is 2 here. Is that not correct?

Comment: no, the regex you posted matches ANY string that contains at least 2 continuous capital letters, so in the test string case, it will match 2 times, one for AB and another one for BC. Try running some regexes here http://www.rubular.com/ (a nice regex playground :D)

Comment: Ah, I thought any string that *is* exactly two capital letters.

Comment: Welcome to the magic word of regexes :). But be careful, sometimes they are great, and sometimes they are just horrible :)

Comment: Thanks for the link by the way, it's a much more convenient environment to test in.